# In NEURON .MOD files what is the order of operations of the sections?

Tags: neural-network, biological-neural-network, neuron-simulator, nmodl

In what order do the commands in NEURON .MOD/NMODL file sections get executed? Specifically, within these blocks: DERIVATIVE, BREAKPOINT and NET_RECEIVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every time-step, the order of execution is as follows:

1. **NET_RECEIVE**: If there is net_send() an event that targets this mechanism, lines here are executed first. Skipped otherwise.
2. Lines in **BREAKPOINT**: The SOLVE ... METHOD line is ignored. All lines after SOLVE are executed. With a `printf()` statement, you would see two calls. However, one of the calls does not actually set any state variables. It is used to compute the derivatives.
3. Finally, the **DERIVATIVE** block: The values for the derivatives (`X' = ...`) are computed. Keep in mind, to get the value by which the state variable actually changes, multiply by `dt`.