# Where does jNeuroML put LEMS commands in generated NEURON .MOD/NMODL?

Tags: biological-neural-network, neuron-simulator, neuroml, lems

How do the following tags in LEMS get mapped into NEURON .MOD/NMODL files:

```
<OnEvent>
   <StateAssignment .. />
</OnEvent>

<OnCondition ... >
   <StateAssignment ... >
</OnCondition>

<DerivedVariable .. />
<ConditionalDerivedVariable .. />
<TimeDerivative .. />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LEMS tags are mapped to NEURON MOD as follows:

- **OnEvent** -> **NET_RECEIVE**: `StateAssignment`s inside `OnEvent` are placed into NET_RECEIVE block of NEURON .MOD. The assignments are put in the order they appear in the LEMS file.
- **OnCondition** -> **BREAKPOINT**: All `if` statements from each `OnCondition` tag are clumped together and placed in BREAKPOINT section, and get executed in the order in which they appear in the LEMS file.
- **DerivedVariable, ConditionalDerivedVariable, TimeDerivative** -> **DERIVATIVE**: These are also clumped together and appear in the DERIVATIVE section. First, all `DerivedVariable` statements, then all `ConditionalDerivedVariable` statements, and finally all `TimeDerivative` statements. As with others, they all are placed in the order they appear.

Notes:

- If you need a `DerivedVariable` that is used by an `OnCondition`, create an *always-executing* `OnCondition` statement with `test="1 .eq. 1"`, with a new `StateVariable`, and place it before any other `OnCondition` statements that will use it.
- Similarly, if you need a `DerivedVariable` that depends on a `ConditionalDerivedVariable`, create an always-executing `ConditionalDerivedVariable` and place it before other `ConditionalDerivedVariable`s that use it.
- Once translated to NEURON MOD, the statements are grouped and executed within each timestep in the following order:

  1. `OnEvent`
  2. `OnCondition`'s
  3. `DerivedVariable`'s
  4. `ConditionalDerivedVariable`'s
  5. `TimeDerivative`'s

See: [In NEURON .MOD files what is the order of operations of the sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921512/in-neuron-mod-files-what-is-the-order-of-operations-of-the-sections)